# jQuery.localize translate jquery.dialog messages

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, localization

I'm using a jQuery Dialog to display some information and jquery-localize to translate the user interface.

To localise I use https://github.com/coderifous/jquery-localize

I have this code in my `<head>`, but I don't know hot to localize the buttons...

```
$('#dialog').dialog({
 autoOpen: false,
 width: 600,
 modal: true,       
 buttons: {
  "Yes, I would like to have this one": function() {
    doSomeStuff();
       $( this ).dialog( "close" );
 },
 "No, I prefer to don't..": function() {
    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Can I use same resource that jQuery.localize uses? And if yes, how can I do that? If not, how can I localize JavaScript strings and values?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Looks like it stores all the localization data in `$.localize.data` so you might be able to pull things out that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jquery.localize uses a `rel` attribute. If you already have jquery.localize set up, you should be able to add the `rel` when you open the dialog:

```
$('#dialog').dialog("open");
$("button.ui-button span:contains('Yes, i would like')").attr("rel","localize[your_value]");
$("button.ui-button span:contains('No, i prefer')").attr("rel","localize[your_value]");
```

Then call localize (taken from the docs - yours may be different):

```
$("rel*=localize").localize("application", { language: "es" });
```

Comment: i get an idea about doing this, but i dont know how to use it in my scenario. in my head i have:   `code`$(function(){  
$('#dialog').dialog({  
 autoOpen: false,  
 width: 600,  
 modal: true,  
 buttons: {  
  "Yes, i would like": function() {  
function() {  
 addValue();  
 $( this ).dialog( "close" );  
},  
  "NO, i dont need": function() {  
function() {  
 $( this ).dialog( "close" );  
 }  
 }  
});`code`  i tried to use your code but with no effect. can you help me with my scenario?